# How to run ZooInspector from Windows

Tags: java, windows, apache-zookeeper

Here's what I did:

- Downloaded Apache ZooKeeper 3.4.6 (.tar file), extracted to C:\cygwin\home\user\zookeeper-3.4.6\
- Ran *ant* at the root of the ZooKeeper folder (C:\cygwin\home\user\zookeeper-3.4.6)
- Navigated to C:\cygwin\home\user\zookeeper-3.4.6\contrib\ZooInspector\
- Ran *ant*, and I get the following error:

Output:

```
Buildfile: C:\cygwin\home\Jean\zookeeper-3.4.6\contrib\ZooInspector\build.xml

BUILD FAILED
C:\cygwin\home\user\zookeeper-3.4.6\contrib\ZooInspector\build.xml:19: Cannot find C:\cygwin\home\user\zookeeper-3.4.6\contrib\build-contrib.xml imported from C:\cygwin\home\user\zookeeper-3.4.6\contrib\ZooInspector\build.xml

Total time: 0 seconds
```

This leaves me with no **.cmd** or **.sh** file to execute. How come the build-contrib.xml file isn't there?

Also, I noticed that there seems to be an already-compiled ZooInspector JAR file: **zookeeper-3.4.6-ZooInspector.jar**. However, attempting to run it with the following command yields failure too:

```
$ java -cp zookeeper-3.4.6-ZooInspector.jar:lib/* org.apache.zookeeper.inspector.ZooInspector
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.inspector.ZooInspector
```

This is a bit frustrating -- setting up the ZooKeeper server was straightforward but for some reason I just can't figure out how to run this standalone GUI. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**For windows**:

```
@echo off
set cp="./*;./lib/*;../../*;../../lib/*"
java -cp %cp% org.apache.zookeeper.inspector.ZooInspector
```

Answer (score 2):

ZooInspector 3.4.6 (that's bundled with ZooKeeper 3.4.6) doesn't seem to be able to connect to a running ZooKeeper instance on Windows.

Better use zkui:
https://github.com/echoma/zkui/wiki/Download

Answer (score 0):

zooInspector just need 3 libraries and 1 jar to load the main class.
 the mainclass lives zookeeper-3.3.0-ZooInspector.jar and it needs jtoaster-1.0.4.jar, zookeeper-3.3.0.jar and finally log4j-1.2.15.jar

After download the tar.gz file from apache servers, you must untar and build with ant. finally copy the zookeeper-3.3.0.jar and log4j-1.2.15.jar to contrib/ZooInspector/lib/. Finally cd to contrib/ZooInspector and launch this command

```
java -jar zookeeper-3.3.0-ZooInspector.jar -cp lib/*
```

Comment: Tried this, got a runtime error:
$ java -jar zookeeper-3.4.6-ZooInspector.jar -cp lib/*
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/zookeeper/
Watcher
        at org.apache.zookeeper.inspector.ZooInspector.main(ZooInspector.java:45
)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.Watcher
        ...

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue today, and created a pre-compiled version, which should work on Windows as well. You can find details here:
https://www.admon.org/scripts/zooinspector-zookeeper-graphic-interface/

Comment: The official release of zooinspector is kinda mess, I will try to build more generic packages with its most recent code base.